# Why does php's in_array return true if passed a 0?

Tags: php, arrays

In the below `in_array(0, $array)` evaluates to `true`. That surprised me. I expected `false`.

I know adding the third parameter to indicate a strict check like `in_array(0, $array, true)` will give me the desired result.

That said, I'm very curious *why* `in_array(0, $array)` evaluates to `true`. At first I thought it was just seeing a string at the 0 index, but `in_array(1, $array)` evaluates to `false` so that doesnt seem to explain it.

#### Example:  [Runable fiddle here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec45e8aa54704aa6ae40d8a86300f746520ed17e)

```
<?php 

$array = [
    'inputs',
    'app',
    'post',
    'server',
];

echo in_array('inputs', $array) ? '"inputs" is in the array...' : '';
echo "\n";

echo in_array(0, $array) ? '0 is also in the array!' : '';
echo "\n";

echo in_array(1, $array) ? '1 is also in the array!' : '1 is NOT in the array!';
```

#### Output:

```
"inputs" is in the array...
0 is also in the array!     <---- huh? 
1 is NOT in the array!
```

Comment: My guess, the type checking is converting your strings into integer based on the type of the first parameter. Try it with a third parameter of `true`

https://3v4l.org/4HQOK vs https://3v4l.org/vgo9Y

Comment: Because `0 == 'str'` evaluates to `true` in PHP.

Comment: @revo as long as the string doesn't start with a number...

Comment: @Nick `str` is `str` literally. It's not anything else. I believe this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @revo @nick is right `1somestring` will turn into `1`, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/deb93597362c17d8028bfa7036427909199f1265

Comment: https://3v4l.org/qJEU4 quick way to test is with var_dump and type casting

Comment: @DelightedD0D I didn't say he is not right!

Comment: @revo, my bad, I missunderstood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because by default [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) uses loose comparisons, so when you pass `0` as an input it attempts to convert the string values in the array to an integer, and they all come out as 0 (because none of them start with a digit; see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)), causing `in_array` to return `true`. It returns false for an input of `1` because all the comparison values are 0.

You will see similar behaviour with [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
print_r(array_keys($array, 0));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

indicating that `array_keys` thinks *every* value in the array is 0.

If you use the `strict` parameter to `in_array` or `array_keys` you will avoid this issue i.e.

```
echo in_array(0, $array, true) ? '0 is also in the array!' : '0 is NOT in the array!';
print_r(array_keys($array, 0, true));
```

Output:

```
0 is NOT in the array!
Array
(
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/k915t)